# How to set the test class which is not labeled?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, prediction

I'm using Weka explorer now and I want to test my classifier with unlabeled data. People on the internet said I can set the class to '?' in order to do that but it doesn't work. Is that only for command lines? How can I do that in the explorer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in having a test case without a label. Setting ? is usefull for training cases, as some methods can infer parameters from unlabeled samples. For testing purposes you **have to** provide label/value/other indicator of correct answer (depending on type of problem).